# Stuck half way replacing broken glass of skylight/velux, do not know how to proceed

Tags: windows, roof, skylight

I am trying to remove the screwed panels around the glass. I am not sure how to remove the top rectangular part, I can not get to the top two screws without removing it.

The metal sheet around the window has been bent around this rectangular. I can possibly pry it open and bend it back, but is there a cleaner way or technique to get this done?

[image: Whole window]
[image: The rectangular part]
[image: Metal cladding marked in red]

Comment: Have you tried calling a glass company and having them come out and just replace the glass? Seems like that would be easier than removing the entire skylight.

Comment: Looks like the glass unit might just pull out towards the bottom if you remove the bottom part and loosen the sides. Or: call the manufacturer's tech support and ask how to do it.

Comment: can you reach any fasteners when the window is open?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't (need to?). Side channels have 3 torx each; the bottom has 2. Remove all of those and then slide it out the bottom?

Comment: No answer, but a corrugated roof seems like a terrible place for a skylight!

Comment: **Resolved** I was able to open the window. I did not realise that I can open the window and tilt it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to be on the roof to replace a Velux pane, nor do you need to remove the weather stripping, you do it from the inside. First you spin the window, flip the locks… then the unit will just lift out.

Velux even made their own video… https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dkxbMlfTFQ

Still

[image]